# convert a non-git project to a git project and push it to gerrit repo

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

i am trying to learn about git and gerrit for a couple days, and there is some error that i can not find a proper solution to it. Here is the error message;

```
*asfaa@asadaf:~/test$ git review -R
Could not connect to gerrit.
Enter your gerrit username: remote0
Trying again with ssh://<username>@<ip>:29418/test
Creating a git remote called "gerrit" that maps to:
    ssh://<username>@<ip>:29418/test
This repository is now set up for use with git-review. You can set the
default username for future repositories with:
  git config --global --add gitreview.username "remote0"
Your change was committed before the commit hook was installed.
Amending the commit to add a gerrit change id.
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://<username>@<ip>:29418/test
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master (no common ancestry)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<username>@<ip>:29418/test'*
```

I get this error after the steps below;

- I create a gerrit folder with the command "ssh -p 29418 user@localhost gerrit create-project project_name"
- Then, i create a folder with the same same in my home directory and convert it to a git repo with "git init" command.
- Then, i copy all the content of the project that i want to push to the gerrit repository in this folder and add all the changes as new changes using "git add --all" command
- I create a .gitreview file and put the host and project attributes in it.
- Commit my changes.
- And lastly, i use "git review -R" command to send my changes to gerrit repository to be reviewed.

Here, in the last step, if i use this command `git push ssh://[username]@[ip]:29418/project_name`, it works. But in this case there is no point in using gerrit repository because i push them directly to git without any review made. Moreover, i assume i will have to deal with this error later when i clone this project to another computer and send my changes to the gerrit repository, so it is better if i learn what am i doing wrong in the above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing git init in a new directory and adding your code I would recommend you clone your new, empty, gerrit repository and make the changes there. So to amend your steps:

1. Create a gerrit folder with the command "ssh -p 29418 user@localhost gerrit create-project project_name"
2. Clone project_name : clone ssh://user@localhost:29418/project_name
3. Copy all the content of the project you want and "git add --all"
4. Create a .gitreview file and put the host and project attributes in it
5. Commit changes
6. git review

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `HEAD -> refs/publish/master (no common ancestry)` is probably because that `master (local)` has not been hooked onto `master (remote, usually: origion/master)`. To ensure this, you can run `git config --list` and look for:

```
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

If this is missing you may set it manually and directly (better not):

```
git config --local branch.master.remote=origin
git config --local branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

or better using:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

the branch name is got from:

```
git branch --all
```

mine is:

```
$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/gerrit/master
  remotes/origin/master
```